# Is there a way to calculate shipping by dollar amount of the order AND the weight?

Tags: paypal

We want to start insuring shipments over $100. Currently we calculate shipping based off the weight of the order. Is there a way to still calculate shipping that way, but then say, if order total > 100.00 add 3.50 to shipping cost?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done if you are using the shipping profile within PayPal for PayPal Payments Standard. The only way to do so would be via custom coding your cart.